# How to write a "retryForever" function in Haskell using exception handling?

Tags: haskell, exception, classy-prelude

I'd like to create a function that can recover from as many errors as is reasonable, and try again. Of course, meaningful handling of errors is covered in other parts of the program - this is a last ditch effort to keep things running. So I wrote this:

```
retryForever prog = catchAny prog progRetry
  where
    progRetry :: SomeException -> m a
    progRetry ex = do
      putStrLn $ pack $ show ex
      threadDelay 4000
      prog
```

Then I wrap my main IO action in `retryForever`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = retryForever $ do
  logger <- newLogger
  -- ...
```

In another part of my program (likely a different green thread), I test this with:

```
error "this is a TEST ERROR"
```

Resulting in:

```
: this is a TEST ERROR
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at XXXX
```

(and the program dies instead of continuing on)

Note that I'm using classy-prelude, for the cases where that may matter, e.g. `catchAny` doesn't handle asynchronous exceptions in there, which may well be the issue here.

Comment: Have you tried crashing on the same thread? Does that work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the program failed, you should run the program `prog` again, but wrapped in `retryForever` such that if it fails again, you thus keep trying:

```
import Control.Monad.Catch(catchAll)

retryForever :: IO a -> IO a
retryForever prog = catchAll prog retry
  where retry ex = do
      putStrLn $ pack $ show ex
      threadDelay 4000
      retryForever prog
```

Comment: FWIW, I was able to use the same `catchAny` - all I had to change was adding in the recursive call to `retryForever`, which I stupidly forgot, somehow thinking that `catchAll` was handling the recursion for me.

Comment: @bbarker: the difference seems to be that `catchAny` catches all *synchronous* errors, whereas `catchAll` catches all exceptions. Although they both probably will do the job :)

Comment: At least, I guess `retryForever` should work if I remember to call it on the "main loop" of each thread.

Comment: @bbarker: yes, probably there will be no difference in that case. So I guess you can use both :).